# Dijkstra Global Path Planner

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I wonder whether there is any document that describes the implementation of the Dijkstra algorithm using ROS. I read the navfn API documentation but the code is not clear to me.

My main concern is whether the Dijkstra algorithm make a complete search on all the cells of the grid or a subset. It was indicated that an interpolated version is implemented by I did not see how interpolation can be used with Dijkstra. Any clarification will be very appreciated.

Furthermore, when the global planner navfn computes a path, how this path is expressed? Is it a sequence of cell coordinate in the grid (row ID, Column ID) or sequence of position?
Which topic published the path output by navfn?

Thanks for any help

Anis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63370/dijkstra-global-path-planner/) by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 253 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to make sense of the NavFn code as well but I haven't come to a total understanding yet either. I would be very much interested in a documentation of the NavFn code as well, or at least somebody that can give some more insight to the code. However, I can try to express what I understood so far to give you some help.

The Dijkstra algorithm operates on a potential matrix which is computed from the global costmap. How it is calculated I don't know yet either, it seems to be a function of the distance from the goal, the distance from the start and the distance from obstacles. The potential matrix can be displayed in rviz over the topic `~<name>/potential` as a PointCloud by setting the NavFn parameter `visualize_potential` to true.
The potential matrix is expanded in a circular fashion until the goal point is reached. For a detailed description of the Dijkstra algorithm check wikipedia.

The path is then computed using a gradient descent on the potential matrix and is published as a nav_msg/Path on the topic `~<name>/plan`. The plan is basically a list of Poses (position and orientation) expressed in your global frame.

---

Originally posted by [Dominik](https://answers.ros.org/users/4965/dominik/) with karma: 68 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RB](https://answers.ros.org/users/6427/rb/) on 2015-02-05**:
Is there any material related to complete understanding of navfn package?
Thanks!!

**Comment by [ParitoshKelkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/24321/paritoshkelkar/) on 2016-03-27**:
I am not able to figure out how the path(grid cells) returned by Dijkstra is used by the gradient descent algorithm. Any thoughts? I thought that gradient descent alone could be used to generate required path.